# How to store compiled groovy script in database to be fetched later on and run it after binding required variables

Tags: java, oracle, grails, groovy, groovyshell

In a Groovy file, i receive inputs from a field which have a groovy script entered by user,let's say:

`def x = a + 5
println x`

I read this as a String and store it in a variable say script.Then i compiled this Script using something like:
    `Script s = new GroovyShell().parse(script)`
Now, what i want is to store this s object in Oracle DB. It's purpose is, i can fetch the compiled code from DB wherever i need and run it by binding the variable to it using something like:

`Binding b = new Binding().setVariable('a', 5))
    s.setBinding(b) //s fetched from database
    s.run()`

Problem: How to store this Script object s in DB. I tried it inserting in the Blob using:
    `ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutput out = null;
         try {
         out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
         out.writeObject(s);
         byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();
         b = sql.getConnection().createBlob();
         b.setBytes(1, yourBytes);
         } finally {
         out.close();
         bos.close();
         }`

But this doesn't seem possible because while serializing the s object, i get the following exception:
    `Caught: java.io.NotSerializableException:     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$2
    java.io.NotSerializableException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$2
    at java_io_ObjectOutput$writeObject.call(Unknown Source)`

What i am hoping to achieve here is performance optimization. Instead of compiling and Running the Groovy Script again and again, i want it to compile once and run whenever required by binding data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read carefully articles ab groovy class loaders, embedding, script class (intelligent recompiling when required). I undersnd You question, at loading probably You need extend GroovyClassLoader

Comment: Saving code is not complete is one squency. What is 's' ? Not store "Script" object (I belive is not Seriazable, understand why), but class

Comment: S is my Compiled Script object. And yes, i know object not being able to be Serialized is causing the exception. I just specified this as the solution i tried but didn't work.What i am looking for is any working alternative solution to perform this task.

Comment: I had some (unfinished) projekt in this area. If are You absolutely sure groovy compilation is problem (probably isn't), else this optimization have not sense. Compiled class is catched in classloader. Next problem You meet in the future, what if Your source imports some classes, need other groovy  etc ... Think carefull You really need this solution

Comment: The scope of script is very limited, just dynamic manipulations of variables. So, i don't suppose i will facing the problems you specified in future. I aim at reducing the overhead of compiling the same code multiple time and instead save it after first compile. The problem i am facing is how to save that compiled groovy code in database and how to retrieve it when needed to run.

Comment: Object way (if I remeber third in documentation, GroovyScriptEngine) hold class in cache, and action can be shot how many times Y want http://www.groovy-lang.org/integrating.html

Comment: This option is viable if both compilation and execution are done in same application. But, in my case, one GUI is responsible of generating the script and other background process is responsible of executing it for result. Since, cache isn't shared inter application, this doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the script in the db as a string (varchar). I would take the hit of compiling on the first hit, but then cache the compiled script. The cache key would be the script source or a hash key of it, so if the source changes, it would recompile. Additional optimizations could be implemented using db notifications.

Comment: In my scenario, one application is responsible of generating the script and storing it and another application is using that script to obtain result. Being two separate applications, there is no common cache shared between them.SO, i can't cache the compiled script and use it whenever desired. And, if i store the compiled script in DB as String, how will i be able to use it when needed? Because String cannot be converted back to the Script Object, which is used to run it.